# Disable INFO messages in Jdeveloper

Tags: java, jdeveloper, message, info

Anybody knows how to get rid of the INFO messages in the console in JDEVELOPER ?

I'm working with web services.

[image]

Comment: Edit the logging.xml and set desired level or Check the docs on Jdeveloper and navigate to `Configure Oracle Diagnostic Logging` and set the desired logging level there.

Comment: Didn't work, I am still getting INFO messages on console.

Answer (score 1):

Under Tools menu, go to Preferences and then navigate to Issues. Set what you want to do with the various messages tabs. You can also disable them all.

Comment: Hi Manisha :) .  I think those are warnings and errors from JDEV .  This is more like a logger type of thing.